# Hosting Silverlight Business Application - Godaddy

Tags: silverlight, forms-authentication

Could you please help me with authentication in Silverlight Business Application.
I opened Silverlight Business Application project using the template (VS2010, Silverlight 4).  I added no extra code, only a godaddy sql server connection entry to Web.config.  Published the project, FTP it over to godaddy server.  I get this errors:

"IIS specified authentication schemes 'Basic, Anonymous', but the binding only supports specification of exactly one authentication scheme...Change the IIS settings so that only a single authentication scheme is used."

I contacted godaddy and they disabled the basic authenthication scheme.  I tried it again and got the same message.  I contact godaddy again (maybe they forgot to hit the save button.)  They confirmed, I am get this error: "IIS specified authentication schemes 'IntegratedWindowsAuthentication, Anonymous' but the binding only supports specification of exactly one authentication scheme..."
Am I missing to do something on my end to get this working?  Please help!  Here is my web.config file:

```
<configuration>
<configSections>  
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="DomainServiceModule" 
        type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule,  
        System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
        PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </httpModules>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <roleManager enabled="true"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">      
    </authentication>
    <profile>
      <properties>
        <add name="FriendlyName"/>
      </properties>
    </profile>  
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
   <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<connectionStrings>
   <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
   <add name="LocalSqlServer"  connectionString="Data Source=myhost; Initial Catalog=mydatabase; User ID=myusername; 
   Password='mypassowrd';" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instruct Godaddy to set authentication scheme to Anonymous only.